# How do I manage database state with git pull Wordpress deployment?

Tags: wordpress, git

I've been researching ways to come up with some kind of deployment process for a Wordpress site I manage.  I keep finding guides [like this one](http://stevegrunwell.github.io/wordpress-git/) that talk about how to manage your configuration but I'm having trouble learning about managing database state.  What are some good ways to manage database state when your Wordpress site exists in a repo?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [Revisr](https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisr/) will help manage your Wordpress git repository, including the database.

Comment: Ah... so the idea here is that you put this on your production install and push changes to your repo, rather than deploying changes with a git pull?

Comment: You can go either direction. I have a local repo for development. When I think the changes are good, I push to the live site.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused... if I update a plugin from v1.7 to 2.0 in my repo, when I push how will the database get updated with the changes for the plugin?

Comment: Revisr will maintain SQL scripts for your database, but it won't manage a database for you. I'm not sure there's a way to do that with git.

Comment: So I'm not sure how revisr is valuable if updating plugins locally can't be pushed to production, but have to be updated manually on production anyways.

Comment: The plugin will be updated, but not necessarily the database. No problem. It's a solution, but maybe not one that meets your needs.